# How to access files on usb drive with Win32_PnPEntity

Tags: c#, usb-drive

I have a list of usb devices from `ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_PnPEntity")`.

I get my desired deviceId like

> "USB\VID_12D1&PID_107E&MI_00\6&26A6F6E6&0&0000"

Is it possible to access files on an usb-drive using that devideId string?

Comment: Once the USB drive gets mounted you should be able to see the files using Windows Explorer and then access the files like any other file on your c:\ drive.

Comment: My mobile phone doesnt have and driver letter.

Comment: What is shown on the Window Explorer?  The device is mounted like a file system.

Comment: See following : https://superuser.com/questions/1157661/how-to-mount-an-android-smartphone-as-a-drive-in-windows

Comment: @jdweng see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffdNY.png

Comment: Did you try \\kai

Comment: Installing webdav is not an option for me.